# implementing static methods - need assistance

Tags: java, jsp

Working on a web application and implementing a class called Calculator that calculates certain things about your body to determine how to focus your diet.

I am implementing this caluclator but I am getting an error. Here is the error; and following it below is an example of the source code. If you could tell me where my problem is that would be incredibly appreciated.

***The Error:***

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 83 in the jsp file: /updateProfile.jsp
Calculator cannot be resolved
80:  a6 = "checked";
81: }
82: 
83: out.println(Calculator.percentBodyFat("f","145","38","38","38","27","27","27",67.0,"6.5")); 
84: 
85: String theName = request.getParameter("name");
86: if(theName != null) 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

***The Source code:***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
package hygeia;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

  public static double percentBodyFat(String sex, String w, String h1,
    String h2, String h3, String a1, String a2, String a3, double height, String wr)  
  {
    //statements
  }
  public static double leanBodyMass(double weight, double percentBodyFat)
  {
    //statements
  }
  public static double protein(double leanBodyMass, int activLevel)
  {
    //statements
  }
}
```

It is able to compile but I cannot get it to work with the jsp.
It seems like it should be very simple.

Comment: i think u have to import caliculator

Comment: the package position is wrong, correct it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the `Calculator` class in your JSP page

```
<%@page import="Calculator"%> <%-- with the complete package of Calculator class--%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not compile, package should be at the top.

Comment: this should be a comment, not answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may fix the problem by importing your Calculator class.

```
<%@page import="Calculator"%>
```